# React useState giving previous state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

So I try make a form with a conditional checkbox using react hook form  but react always give me the previous state of the checkbox value when i save my data in the context.
i see some people say you have to add a useEffect cause useState is asynchronous but nothing change for me.

my code:

```
const ContactFormMain: FunctionComponent<any> = ({ nextFormStep }) => {
  const { saveForm, infos } = useContext(ContactFormContext) as ContactFormDataType;
  const { register } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur",
  })
  const [formUserData, setFormUserData] = useState<IContactFormData | {}>(infos[0]);
  const [val, setVal] = useState(false)
  const [sharingChoice, setSharingChoice] = useState<string>(infos[0].sharePatientInfo)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(sharingChoice)
    console.log(val)
  }, [sharingChoice, val])

  const updateContext = (e: FormEvent<HTMLButtonElement | HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    console.log('afterSetState', formUserData);
    setFormUserData({
      ...formUserData,
      [e.currentTarget.id]: e.currentTarget.value
    })
   
  }

  const handleCheck = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    console.log(e.target.checked)
    setVal(!val)
    if(val === true) {
      setSharingChoice("Des informations concernant le patient sont transmises dans ce ticket.")
    } else {
      setSharingChoice("Il n'y pas d'informations patient partagées dans ce ticket.")
    }
    console.log('checkedValue', val)
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
  const updateContextWithCheckBox = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> ) => {
    handleCheck(e);
    updateContext(e);
  }

  const handleSaveUserInfo = (e: FormEvent, formData: IContactFormData | any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    saveForm(formData)
    console.log('context', formData)
    nextFormStep();
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSaveUserInfo(e, formUserData)}>
        <label htmlFor='subjects'>
          Raisons
        </label>
        <div id="subjects">
          <button type="button" id="subject" value='Détection de pathologie subtile' onClick={updateContext}> Détection de pathologie subtile </button>
          <button type="button" id="subject" value="Gain de temps" onClick={updateContext}> Gain de temps </button>
          <button type="button" id="subject" value="impact sur la prise en charge" onClick={updateContext}> impact sur la prise en charge </button>
          <textarea {...register("description")} id="description" name="description" defaultValue={infos[0].description} onChange={updateContext} />
          <label htmlFor='sharePatientInfo'>
            Ne contient pas d&apos;info patient
          </label>
          <input type="checkbox" placeholder="infoPatient " {...register("sharePatientInfo ")} id="sharePatientInfo" checked={val} value={sharingChoice} name="sharePatientInfo" onChange={updateContextWithCheckBox} />
          <button type='submit'>Suivant</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  )
}

export default ContactFormMain;
```

any idea?

Comment: How *specifically* are you observing the problem?  For example, there are a variety of `console.log` statements here.  Which one demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer**

You have added a `useEffect` but you aren't putting it to any use. The purpose of the `useEffect` is to synchronize your state. Feel free to read more about the purpose in these React docs: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects

There are 2 moments where you assume that the value will be immediately updated in the state (even though the update is asynchronous), so let's focus on each.

**Fix Part 1**

```js
const handleCheck = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
  console.log(e.target.checked)
  setVal(!val)        // <-- here we tell React to update the "val" state
  if(val === true) {  // <-- but it is probably not updated yet when we get here
    // ...so we probably end up doing the wrong thing in this "if" block
    setSharingChoice("Des informations concernant le patient sont transmises dans ce ticket.")
  } else {
    setSharingChoice("Il n'y pas d'informations patient partagées dans ce ticket.")
  }
  console.log('checkedValue', val)
}
```

Let's fix it. It's easy enough. All we have to do is use a variable from our local scope that we know will not change, such as the previous `val` or the `e.target.checked` value.

```js
const handleCheck = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
  console.log(e.target.checked);
  const prevVal = val;     // <-- we save this for later
  setVal(!prevVal);        // <-- tell React to update this value **asynchronously**
  if(!prevVal === true) {  // <-- the new value of "val" will be "!prevVal" so use that instead
    // ...and now we are ending up in the right part of the "if" block
    setSharingChoice("Des informations concernant le patient sont transmises dans ce ticket.")
  } else {
    setSharingChoice("Il n'y pas d'informations patient partagées dans ce ticket.")
  }
  console.log('checkedValue', val)
}
```

**Fix Part 2**

Now the other part.

```js
const updateContext = (e: FormEvent<HTMLButtonElement | HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement>): void => {
  console.log('afterSetState', formUserData);
  setFormUserData({
    ...formUserData,
    [e.currentTarget.id]: e.currentTarget.value 
    //                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // this is actually the "sharingChoice" state value, which isn't updated yet
    // since that update happens asynchronously
  })
}
```

There are a few ways to fix this one.

*Quick tangent/suggestion*: One method I'd recommend learning more about is using [`useRef`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useRef) when you have a value you want to track that changes over time in the lifecycle of the component, but shouldn't trigger a re-render when its value changes. From the code you provided, it looks like the `formUserData` and `sharingChoice` could be refs instead of state, since nothing in the UI needs to update when they change, but in the greater context of your component, that may not be the case.

But for the quick fix here, just move the work done by the `updateContext` call from `updateContextWithCheckBox` method to the `useEffect` block.

```js
const updateContextWithCheckBox = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> ) => {
  handleCheck(e);
  //updateContext(e); // <-- don't do it here
}
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setFormUserData((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    "sharePatientInfo": sharingChoice  // <-- now we actually get the latest sharingChoice value
  }));
}, [sharingChoice, setFormUserData]);
```

Comment: thanks! i will test a method using useRef in another project.